# no such file to load -- openid/store/filesystem (Rails omniauth)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

This is first time I'm trying to use Omniauth. While I was testing https://github.com/pt/devise-omniauth-example this example from github I came across an error

```
 .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require': no such file to load -- openid/store/filesystem (LoadError)
```

Here is my Gemfile content

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rake'
gem 'rails'
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem 'devise', :git => 'git://github.com/plataformatec/devise', :branch => 'master'
gem "omniauth", "1.0.1"
gem 'paperclip'
gem "simple_form", "~> 1.5.2"
gem 'twitter_oauth', '0.4.3'
gem "rest-client", "1.6.7", :require => "restclient"
gem "sluggable"


group :development, :test do
 gem 'rspec-rails'
 gem 'fixjour'
end
```

I search web but there was no luck.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/OpenID-and-Google-Apps):

If you get "openid/store/filesystem (LoadError)" then you may need to add this to your Gemfile:

`gem "oa-openid"`

Answer (score 1):

This is due to various versions of Gems you are using and the dependencies among them.
In the example at https://github.com/pt/devise-omniauth-example,
if you notice the [Gemfile](https://github.com/pt/devise-omniauth-example/blob/master/Gemfile) ,there is

```
gem 'omniauth', '0.2.0'
```

but in your Gemfile above, you are using

```
gem "omniauth", "1.0.1"
```

Comment: Yes because I wanted to use all latest Gemfile.

Comment: Nope for me, but I finally got it fixed by adding gem "oa-openid", pls check the link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add `gem 'ruby-openid-apps-discovery'`, and add below in `application.rb`.

```
require 'omniauth-openid'
require 'openid'
require 'openid/store/filesystem'
require 'gapps_openid'
```